# Zend framework 2: Lucene autoload

Tags: lucene, zend-framework2

I have same problem as this question [Class 'ZendSearch\Lucene\Lucene' not found ZendFramework2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696121/class-zendsearch-lucene-lucene-not-found-zendframework2).  I have tried both solutions but I still have the same problem. I am guessing that autoload is the problem.

This is my autoload_namespaces.php file in \vendor\ZendSearch\vendor\composer folder:

```
    // autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer
     $vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
     $baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

     return array(
         'Zend\\Stdlib\\' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zend-stdlib'),
         'ZendSearch' => array($baseDir . '/library'), 
     );
```

Is this correct code? I cant find a example of Lucene search with Zend Framework 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:
1. Edit composer.json in root folder of application, add

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "ZendSearch": "library/"
         }
    },
```

1. run

   ```
   $ php composer.phar install
   ```

3.This will generate new autoload file  autoload_namespaces.php file in \vendor\ZendSearch\vendor\composer folder. Code should look like this.

```
   <?php

// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Zend\\' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library'),
    'ZendXml' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendxml/library'),
    'ZendSearch\\' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/ZendSearch/library'),
);
```